# Variable undefined when updated inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I declare `user_properties` outside of my function. I then get my data from firebase and try to store it in user_properties but it ends up being undefined.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

```
var user_properties;

get_user_properties = new Firebase("https://<MY-URL>/users/"+auth.uid+"/properties");
get_user_properties.once('value', function (dataSnapshot) {
  user_properties = dataSnapshot.val();
});

//undefined
console.log(user_properties);
```

Comment: The function is asynchronous, when your console log is called the request hasnt finished yet

Answer (score 0):

I've provided for you a simple example.

```
var foo,
    obj = new Bar("some text");

obj.set("cute cat", function(cat){
    foo = "my lovely cat";
});

console.log(foo); // undefined
obj.doo();
console.log(foo); // "my lovely cat"
```

With this constructor function

```
function Bar(c){
    this.mcat = c;
    this.callback;

    /* this method only saves that callback function */
    this.set = function(catname, callback){
        this.mcat = catname;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    /* this method calls that callback function */
    this.doo = function(){
        this.callback();
    }
}
```